# Variation of d'Alembertian operator

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, variational-calculus

I am working in a higher derivative quantum gravity theory, and I'm having trouble with the variation of d'Alembertian operator.

Suppose we have the following action:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal S[g]=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} R \: \square^kR
\end{equation}
When varying this with respect to the metric in order to find the associate field equations from the variational principle, one needs to calculate something like:
\begin{equation}
\delta \left( \square^kR \right)
\end{equation}
Or in the simplest case:
\begin{equation}
\delta \left( \square R \right)
\end{equation}

Can someone help me out to find the variation of this term?

Comment: i think that the variation on the box of the ricci scalar $\delta \Box R$ would be zero. It is a total derivative and it should not add to the equations of motion. But i'm not sure. Of course $\delta(R  \Box R)$ is not going to be zero.

Comment: I'm not sure, this variations on the action are sometimes quite tricky, specially when this kind of differential operators come to the party. The usual method I've seen consists on computing $\delta(R\square R)$ with the "leibniz rule".

Comment: Anyway, the $\delta \Box R$ is indeed zero. The same way $\delta \Box \phi$ is zero but $\delta(\phi  \Box \phi)$ yields the kinetic term of the scalar field. I recommend using xAct to derive the equations of motion, the final form looks terrible. It seems to require tons of patience to derive it by hand. Good luck! The Leibniz rule is the method you're right.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the kinetic term of a scalar field is a great example of what you said. Thanks! I think I'll have to do it by Software, it's getting too messy, especially in the general case. Anyway, I'm still not sure how to proceed with the Leibniz rule, if i write $\delta(R\square R) =(\delta R)\square R + R\delta(\square R)$, the last term is $0$?

Comment: If the scalar field is a good example, continue thinking as you're dealing with it. Is $\phi \delta \Box \phi$ zero??

Comment: It's not zero and you're right, this is not different from the ricci scalar case. They're both scalar fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recall the definition of the d'Alembertian acting on some scalar $\phi$:
$$\square \phi = g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{\mu}\left(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\phi\right)$$
The first equality is simply the definition, the second equality is a standard exercise in GR courses. From a GR course you should also be familiar with varying $g$ etc. So, from here you should be able to do the maths. It may be faster to rewrite your action using differential forms.

Btw.: What's the meaning of the index $k$ in your notation?

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm gonna try it this way. I knew the equality, but it didn't came to my mind. Sorry, I forgot to talk about k, k is just a power of the d'Alembert operator, not any index.

Comment: Oh, a power. Sounds horrible. ;) Without having done the computation my gut feeling tells me that differential forms + Stokes theorem might be helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's the deal with higher derivative teories, differential operators have high powers and that's a complete pain! Thank you so much, I'm gonna try with brute force and if I fail I'll try with differential forms.